# Shih tzu skin problems

Tags: dogs, skin-condition

I have a shih tzu that is about 7 years old. He keeps getting these weird little buildups of white stuff in his fur that clump together and stick to his skin. He does itch at them and if they get left there I noticed his skins does get a bit red on the spot.

Normally when he goes outside he stays in the shade and only for about 5-10 minutes so I'm pretty sure that he doesn't have hot spots. The things that he gets is just kind of weird, it's not really a scab, it's almost like a white sticky powder.

He has had frequent yeast infections in his ears before, but the spots aren't black where the issue occurs. I did buy some anti fungal shampoo thinking it would help him, I haven't used it yet.

I'm just trying to figure out what it could be before I take him to the vet. The closest vet that we have isn't always honest to me, so I normally take him to one about 45mins away. So I'm just trying to get some info, I looked it up online and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

It ended up just being a sever case of doggy dandruff.

I gave him his first treatment bath last night and gave him a light brushing to remove the dead skin. He seems to be less itchy.

Just wanted to share this information just in case someone in the future has a similar issue with their dog. Was kind of worried at first it was something worse. But it ended up being something small.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks. Normally I would ask you to take the pupper to a vet, since the doc knows best. For any future occurrence of the same infection, you may use the given remedy.